# Display selected values in popup window

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to know how to display list of selected values in popup window as dropdown.
here is my `clientview.jsp` code

```
</head>
    <body>
        <jsp:include page="clientusrmapheader.jsp">
            <jsp:param name="" value="true"/>
       </jsp:include>

          <div class="tcc" style="min-height:620px; width:100%;float:left;">
              <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="clientAccounts" action="/client_user_map.html">
                           <div id='baseDiv'>
                                         <input type="submit" value="CLIENT-USER MAP"/>
                                        <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/clientusermap.jsp"%>
                </div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><span class="selectALLWrap"> <input type='checkbox' id='selectALL' onclick='selectALLQuestion()'></span><span>Select</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                        <th class="sortable" id='clientName' >Client Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
               <tbody style="font-size: 18px;font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Medium';">
                   <c:forEach items="${clientAccountsList}" var="clientAccount">
                        <tr>
                            <td><div class="checkBoxSel"><form:checkbox path="clientName" value="${clientAccount.clientName}"/> </div></td>
                            <td>${clientAccount.clientName}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
            </table> 
              </form:form>
              </div>
    </body>
```

when above code executes i get list of clients .. now i want to select few client and click on client-user map ... those values should dispaly as popup...

I have written another jsp where selected client appears..

here is clientusermap.jsp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/clientusermap.css" />
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
          $("#baseDiv").click(function(e) {
            $("#popUpDiv").show();
             });  
        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="tcc" style="min-height:620px; width:100%;float:left;">   
           <form:form modelAttribute="clientAccounts">
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <tr>
    <td class = "select">select user :         
    </td>   
    <td ALIGN="center">
       <select>        

       </select>
    </td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class = "select">List of Clients :         
    </td> 

    <td ALIGN="center">
        <div id="popUpDiv">
            <form:select path="clientName" id="selectPopUp">
          <form:option value="-1">Select</form:option>
         <form:options items="${clientNameList}"  />
        </form:select>
        </div>
    </td>        
</tr>
    </TR>
</table>
</form:form>
<input TYPE="submit" VALUE="save">
<input TYPE="reset" VALUE="cancle"> 
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhect.png)

Comment: Did not got what you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: the values which i selected in clientview.jsp should display in popup..

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, what problem are you facing?

Comment: <script>
             <c:set var = "listClientName" value="${clientNameList}"></c:set>
            <c:if test="${fn:length(listClientName) gt 0}">
                $(".tcc").show();
            </c:if>
            
        </script>i wrote this script in clientusermap.jsp page and included this page in clientview.jsp then its only displaying new page but i want to display as popup